# Expand sections in MvxExpandableTableViewSource at the beggining

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

TableView with MvxExpandableTableViewSource as source has all sections collapsed at the beginning. Is it possible to expand them or just some of them programmatically at the beginning?